# Awk source functions file

Tags: awk

Is there a way to source functions and variables from a file with awk?

What I am looking for is a way sourcing/including functions and variables in a similar way we do for shell scripts:

I tried source, include but I get:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ include /tmp/awk-functions }{myfunc}' file
awk: fatal: division by zero attempted
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe `igawk` is what you're looking for:

http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_igawk.htm

[Want an AWK that implements '@include'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16115291/want-an-awk-that-implements-include)

Answer (score 0):

You do like this:

```
var="/tmp/awk-functions"
awk -v t="$var" '{print t}' file
```