# Is there an rc file for awk?

Tags: awk

There are certain functions I would like to make available to every `awk` command I run, so I would like to put the line `--file MyLibrary.awk` into some kind of global configuration which will be loaded on every run of `awk`.

However, after consulting the `man` page, the closest thing I could find was `AWKPATH`which does not remove the need to pass the flag on every command.

```
 The  AWKPATH  environment  variable can be used to provide a list of directories that gawk searches when looking for        
 files named via the -f and --file options.
```

Another alternative is to use `alias` command inside `.bashrc` to cause every call to `awk` to be replaced by `awk -f MyLibrary.awk`, but that seems a little hacky.

**Is there a built-in way to load a configuration for `awk` on every run?**

Comment: The `alias` idea doesn't seem all that "hacky" to me. :-)

Comment: @ooga, That alias can grow very long if you have more than 5 files that you want to source.

Comment: How about one file with a bunch of `@include`s?

Comment: @ooga, That would certainly be better, although not as good as a real `.awkrc`. I didn't think of that before, and I think that would be an improvement over what I currently have.

Comment: You could even call it `.awkrc`! You could also ask the gawk maintainers to add a real `.awkrc` in the future. (So maybe you should call yours `.myawkrc` just in case!)

Answer (score 0):

I just looked over the source code of `GNU awk` and there is no reference to a global configuration file, so the answer is currently **No**.

Answer (score 0):

You can include functions with `igawk`:

[Awk source functions file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24498042/awk-source-functions-file)

As long as you include the functions file the functions will be available.